# Apply CSS in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to center a specific element in one specific page. If I try using CSS such this:

```
#returning_user_search_box {
    position:absolute !important;
    width:50% !important;
    height:300px !important;
    left:0 !important;
    right:0 !important;
    margin:auto !important;
}
```

My element is well centered according to my need. The problem is my element is also present is some other page where is no need to apply specific style. So I tried to use javascript such this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('specific_page.php') != -1) {
    var style = document.getElementById('returning_user_search_box').style;
    style.position     = 'absolute';
    style.right        = '0';
    style.left         = '0';
    style.width        = '50%';
    style.height       = '300px';
    style.margin       = 'auto';
}
```

but here my element is not centered I don't know why. I looked if is possible to add "important!" property in javascript but it seem is not possible.

I precise I don't have access to html of the page because is located on remote server not controlled by me. I can only interact with JS or CSS.

Comment: Use a class. Also, how are you able to change JS and CSS but not HTML? That seems like an… unfortunate setup.

Comment: I use a remote software solution which do not allow to change html. This software allow to make customization but only by adding code in dedicated css and js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your css selector to include a page-specific parent selector:

```
body.onlyTheRequiredPages #returning_user_search_box { ... }
```

You can also create another selector that resets your element style:

```
.specific-page-el {
  position : absolute
  right    : '0'
  ...
}
```

And modify the class of that element via javascript

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('specific_page.php') != -1) {
  document.getElementById('returning_user_search_box').className = "specific-page-el"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can like this:

Simple HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <span>
        Hello World
    </span>
</div>
```

Simple CSS:

```
div#container
{
    background-color:#900!important; //Red color here. JS will change it to Blue.
}
```

Simple JS:

```
document.getElementById('container').setAttribute("style","background-color:#009!important;");
```

But inline style is the worst thing to do.

Link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YhSNv/3/).

Or use different JS like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YhSNv/5/).

```
style=document.getElementById('container').style;
style.setProperty("background-color","#009","!important;");
```